# Creating groups comparable based on a number of variables

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a number of students and I want to divide them into groups. I have measured 5 skills in my students. The goal is to assign students to groups in such as a way that all groups have comparable levels of each skill. In other words I want each of the skills to be distributed comparably across groups, and not concentrated in some groups. What statistical analysis may do this? Preferably in SPSS

Answer (score 1):

You probably want your groups to have a certain size, too?

This looks more like a **resource allocation** rather than a clustering problem to me. Think of skills as resources.